# I cant click on item inside my menu. My menu opens and everything is displayed normally, but nothing happens when I click

Tags: java, android, menu

I cant click on item inside my menu. My menu opens and everything is displayed normally, but nothing happens when I click. I don't know why and searched for information but it doesn't help me.
This my XML code profile__detail_menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_vert_24"
        android:title="">
    <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/change_name"
                android:title="Change name"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"
                />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/new_photo"
                android:title="New photo"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_a_photo_24"
                />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/log_out"
                android:title="Log out"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_login_purp_24"
                />
    </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This my Java code.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.profile__detail_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.change_name:
                Toast.makeText(this, "change_name selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.new_photo:
                Toast.makeText(this, "new_photo selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.log_out:
                Toast.makeText(this, "log_out selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing which I feel is wrong is your menu XML file. For some reason you have a menu tag inside a menu tag. So there is sort of a sub menu if you get my point? But you're not inflating that actually.

Modify the XML as follows

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".YourActivityName"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/change_name"
                android:title="Change name"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_edit_24"
                />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/new_photo"
                android:title="New photo"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_a_photo_24"
                />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/log_out"
                android:title="Log out"
                app:showAsAction="always|withText"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_login_purp_24"
                />
</menu>
```

I have updated your menu as per you code. If you need, add more items to it.

Comment: when I write like you said, the icons next to each of the Items disappear

Comment: @Valery Add the `app:showAsAction="always"` to all the items.

Comment: Also it works if you have space @Valery
Do you want to show it every time?

Comment: this should show up when i click on the three dots in the toolbar

Comment: Try adding `app:showAsAction="always|withText"`. And try inflating your menu and clicking. Let me know the result so that I can help further. I am having trouble understanding rn.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try copying that menu, add the tools context and your activity name.